# How to using groovy to get all folder names under a workspace in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a question about how to get all folder names under a workspace by Groovy in Jenkins Pipeline.

the structure of this workspace looks just like this:

```
/A
/B
/C
/D
```

My Goald is to put A, B, C and D in an array such as names["A","B", "C", "D"]

any Solution?

Comment: Courtesy, Mr. Haki: [Groovy Goodness: Working on Files or Directories (or Both) with FileType](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2010/04/groovy-goodness-working-on-files-or.html)

Comment: hmm, that is not what I want

Comment: Don't use Groovy for this, use shell code instead. Groovy code always runs on master whereas shell code runs on the current node, as expected. You can capture output of shell code from Groovy code, using `returnStdout: true` parameter. Then use Groovy to split the result, e. g. `def names = (sh script: "your shell code", returnStdout: true).trim().split('\n')`

Comment: Hi, can you give me more information or an concret example?

Comment: You can use the [findFiles](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace) (from the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin) that returns a list of all files on the workspace according to the given glob.

Comment: have you figured this out? i want to actually get at the description of the folder